# First instance of robots killing a non-human animal?

Tags: history-of

This is kind of grim, I realize. I am rereading The Second Variety and a quirky, almost humorous bit is, "Major Hendricks went on. Off to the right something scuttled, something round and metallic. A claw, going lickety-split after something. Probably after a small animal, a rat. They got rats, too. ***As a sort of sideline.***" (Emphasis mine.)

How Philip K. Dickian is "As sort of a sideline." The only other instance that comes to mind is the Dark Mirror episode *Metalhead* where the dog-like killer robots have killed the livestock (pigs) of a nearby farm. (Coincidentally, teddy bears show up in both stories.)

So, in these two stories, we have robots who do not simply kill their creators, perhaps for reasons we can almost sympathize with -- because they want freedom or maybe they resent even being brought into existence; instead the robots are antilife. They might have been originally programmed to kill humans, protecting property but it is unlikely they were programmed to protect against pigs and no reason, even if given moral general directives, for them to plausibly see pigs as a threat; if the robots in either story kill animals, it is just because they are meant to be shown as purely evil.

**Summary of Question:** First story in which robots also kill animals, especially non-threatening ones?

Comment: It’s possible a clearer definition of "robots" might be necessary. For example, what about the automated guns that kill lots of xenomorphs in the directors cut of *Aliens*? Would that count (obviously not the earliest example)? In other words, how smart does an automated weapon have to be for it to be a "robot"?

Comment: @ToddWilcox: I am thinking of a rogue robot no longer under the control of humans and dangerous not just to humans but also animals, as in Metalhead and Second Variety.

Comment: Clifford D. Simak's 1977 novel "A Heritage of Stars" includes a robot who, after the collapse of the civilization that built him, overcomes his non-violence programming to kill bears to provide himself with grease for his moving parts. He prefers grizzly bear grease.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that the example to beat is "The Mechanical Mice" in 1941.

The most famous all killing robots are the Berserkers, starting in 1963.

> The Berserker series is a series of space opera science fiction short stories and novels by Fred Saberhagen, in which robotic self-replicating machines strive to destroy all life.
>
> These Berserkers, named after the human berserker warriors of Norse legend, are doomsday weapons left over from an interstellar war between two races of extraterrestrials. They all have machine intelligence, and their sizes range from that of an asteroid, in the case of an automated repair and construction base, down to human size (and shape) or smaller. The Berserkers' bases are capable of manufacturing more and deadlier Berserkers as the need arises. The Berserker hypothesis, formed as a possible solution to the Fermi paradox, takes its name from the series.
>
> The first story, "Without a Thought" (originally published as "Fortress Ship")[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berserker_(novel_series)) (1963), is a puzzle story, whose protagonist must find a way to simulate intelligence to fool an enemy trying to determine whether there was any conscious being present in a spaceship.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berserker_(novel_series)

https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?72643

The article helpfully mentions similar concepts, a few of which may satisfy the question and be earlier than Berserkers.

> A similar premise, though on a much smaller scale, was previously introduced by Walter M. Miller, Jr., in the 1954 short story "I Made You", described by reviewer N. Samuelson as "A pure 'sorcerer’s apprentice' sketch, about a war machine on the moon which kills anyone who comes within its range, including one of its programmers, because its control circuits are damaged."[2](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?72643)

https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55872

> the Claws, self-replicating, self-improving killer robots from the Philip K. Dick story Second Variety, which were designed by the United Nations following a devastating nuclear war with Russia, and intended to kill any human not wearing a special wristband. The book was adapted into the 1995 film Screamers

https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40961

If the Claws satisfy the requirements, their date of 1953 would make them an earlier example than the Berserkers.

Even earlier is "The Mechanical Mice", *Astounding Science Fiction*, January 1941, by Maurice G. Hugi (and maybe also Eric Frank Russell).

https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?71451

The robots in this story might be trying to overthrow humanity.  Since their worker robots are mouse sized, they do have some conflicts with cats.

When a street cat knocks a worker robot onto its back, a warrior robot comes out to fight the cat.  The cat loses.

> Three quarters of an hour later, Police Officer Burke had worked his way around to the fatal spot.  Putting his flash on the body, he rolled the supine body over with his foot. Its throat was cut.  Its throat had been cut with an utter savagery that had half severed its head from its body.  Burke scowled down at it.  He was no lover of cats himself, but he found difficulty imagining anyone hating like that.

As Burke calls for police to investigate a mysterious robbery he finds another dead cat.  And when the other police arrive:

> The first said, "Cats!  I'll say somebody's got it in for cats!  We passed two a couple of blocks away. They were bang in the middle of the street, flat in the headlights, and had been dammed near guillotined.  Their bodies were still warm."

So I would say that "The Mechanical Mice" in 1941 would be the first example of robots which sometimes kill non-human animals. The first I remember at the moment, I mean.